# Jquery Multi level dropdown plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery plugin to show user a hierarchical list. The user can then select parent or child. I have made a fiddle which you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/wujz8jqj/.

The issue is that I can select the child but not the parent. So if an element has children I can only select the children. In other terms I can only select the leaf items if we talk in tree context.

The plugin I am using is this one, http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Animated-Multi-level-jQuery-Dropdown-Plugin.html.

In the fiddle the structure is like this

```
item 1
item 2
   item 2.1
   item 2.2
...
```

So the issue here would be I can't select item 2. Any thoughts? I am thinking of adding an icon so if the user selects that icon that item gets selected.

Comment: Try to use another plugin.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki any options you have in mind?

Comment: Kendo UI , try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qx919w6o

Comment: @KishoreSahas I tried kendo before but it was giving me an error. But let me trying it again and get back to you. If it works it seems perfect.

Comment: If the parent itself is a link then it will not prevent the sub level menu and just open the link which is added in its href. So you can add same item in its parent as child item

Comment: What about adding an expand button to every `<li>` and making a regular `click` select that `<li>`?

Comment: @KishoreSahas I get this error Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined in file kendo.all.min.js:8. This is the reason I switched away from kendo.

Comment: @Thomas yes that is the idea I am trying to achieve but no luck. Can I get a snippet from you?

Comment: @RohanKumar didn't get you.

Comment: Hi when you are getting this error ?

Comment: @Chaudhry Mohsin Ali I'm at work atm so I have no time to write and test it now, just have a good look at the JS, it manipulates the DOM a lot so you need to intergrate this button (a div with this one http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/angle-right/) and `on click` call `$('select, ul').dropdown` (change the selector)

Comment: @Thomas let me try that.

Comment: @KishoreSahas it is when the page loads I guess. When it reads the kendo.all.min.js file.

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli the issue was because it was having an old version of kendo .. here is the latest one .. http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qx919w6o/2/

Comment: @KishoreSahas the error is gone but I get an empty list.

Comment: which browser you are using, the fiddle works in chrome for me .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `kendo ui` see the below snippet.

```js
var dropdown = $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [{
        text: "",
        value: ""
    }],
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    open: function (e) {
        // If the treeview is not visible, then make it visible.
        if (!$treeviewRootElem.hasClass("k-custom-visible")) {
            $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function () {
                dropdown.close();
                $treeviewRootElem.addClass("k-custom-visible");
            });
        }
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
var $dropdownRootElem = $(dropdown.element).closest("span.k-dropdown");

var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    select: function (e) {
        // When a node is selected, display the text for the node in the dropdown and hide the treeview.
        $dropdownRootElem.find("span.k-input").text($(e.node).children("div").text());
        $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function () {
            $treeviewRootElem.removeClass("k-custom-visible");
        });
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");
var $treeviewRootElem = $(treeview.element).closest("div.k-treeview");

// Hide the treeview.
$treeviewRootElem.width($dropdownRootElem.width())
    .css({
    "border": "1px solid grey",
        "display": "none",
        "position": "absolute"
});

// Position the treeview so that it is below the dropdown.
$treeviewRootElem.css({
    "top": $dropdownRootElem.position().top + $dropdownRootElem.height(),
        "left": $dropdownRootElem.position().left
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    // Ignore clicks on the treetriew.
    if ($(e.target).closest("div.k-treeview").length == 0) {
        // If visible, then close the treeview.
        if ($treeviewRootElem.hasClass("k-custom-visible")) {
            $treeviewRootElem.slideToggle('fast', function () {
                $treeviewRootElem.removeClass("k-custom-visible");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<ul id="treeview">
  <li data-expanded="true">Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1.1</li>
      <li>Item 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-expanded="true">Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
      <li>Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<input id="dropdown"></input>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qx919w6o

Comment: I am using Chrome as well. But I don't see the list being populated.

Comment: just for a clarification , is the fiddle (as it is) working at ur side .

Comment: so it is not working while u implement in you project, right ? can you make code snippet from ur project (in a fiddle) along with the error .